# Get actual content height with Javascript (or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are many ways of getting the height of a document, but due to different browser implementations most of them (I believe) return the highest of a number of values ... which is fine most of the time.

In my case I have a number of elements on the page that I know to be a smaller height than the window and viewport heights. What I'm trying to get is the actual height of all the rendered elements.

Things that don't work (with testing in Firefox):

1. `$(document).height(); // gives the window height`
2. `document.body.scrollHeight; // gives 7, its always 7 I don't know why`
3. `document.body.offsetHeight; // also gives 7`
4. `document.documentElement.clientHeight; // sometimes gives window height`
5. `document.documentElement.scrollHeight; //gives window height`
6. `document.documentElement.offsetHeight; generally gives a value in the range of 23`

At present I'm thinking that the way around this might be to insert a `div` with `height: 0` at the bottom of my page and grab `$(div).offset().top`, but I feel that this is highly likely to go wrong at some point in the future.

So before I do that ...

Is there a way of knowing the content height when it's less than the window height?

**EDIT:**

People have asked for clarification. Heres a jsFiddle example of what I want / the results I'm getting.
https://jsfiddle.net/8Lu2zcw8/1/

Running that results in the same value for Win Height: and Doc Height being written out to the console.

**EDIT2:**

My issue was due to the body not wrapping the content correctly due to floated and absolutely positioned elements, as pointed out by @tim-vermaelen in the comments to his solution.

Comment: `$(document).height(); // gives the window height` no, it gives the document height: https://jsfiddle.net/9nm032hs/. Any increase would be caused by the default padding placed on the body by the browser, which you should fix with a reset stylesheet. It's difficult to help you when all you've shown is what does not work, not specifics of the problem. What are the differences between browsers caused by? What is your HTML?

Comment: Added jsFiddle example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use `$(document.body).height()`.

In CSS you have to put:

```
html,
body { height: 100%; }
```

This will only give correct results in case of body padding, margin and borders of the body element are 0. When direct children are floating or put on position absolute, the height of these elements doesn't count. Hence for floating elements you always clearfix the parent to solve these wrapping issues.

If not you can use `$(document.body).outerHeight(includeMargin)`

Comment: $(document.body).outerHeight(false); gives the same as document.body.scrollHeight (7)      $(document.body).outerHeight(true); gives the same as document.documentElement.offsetHeight(23)

Comment: So inspect with firebug the body height, see the "computed" tab and compare these with the elements that are inside the body element. If you notice the body is smaller than the elements height, the body is not wrapped around the elements like it should. Usually caused by floating elements or position absolute.

Comment: Thanks Tim! You were right, the body wasn't wrapped as the whole page was made out of floated elements in an absolutely positioned div.... In my defense its old code being tweaked..

Comment: This is best practice, passing the element reference directly rather than relying on the selector engine makes this a clear winner.

Comment: Great, I completed my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).height()` will give you content size, not window's. If it gives you window's size, then you probably messed up your CSS. Also, you can try `$('body').height()`